# Backtick (`) needed in class binding?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

When I bind the `class` attribute to Vuetify's `v-chip`, I have to use backtick:

```html
<v-chip small :class="`${project.status}`">
                {{ project.status }}
</v-chip>
```

But if I use the code below, why does it show an error?

```html
<v-chip small :class="{{project.status}} ">
                {{ project.status }}
</v-chip>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is invalid syntax in any Vue version:

```
<v-chip small :class="{{project.status}} ">
```

`v-bind` and `:` colon shorthand expect an expression as a value. `` `${project.status}` `` is valid JavaScript expression that is evaluated to stringified `project.status` value. `{{project.status}}` isn't valid JavaScript expression because it contains extra `{{` and `}}` interpolation delimiters.

A correct Vue 1.x syntax would be to use interpolation delimiters without `v-bind`:

```
<v-chip small class="{{project.status}}">
```

This syntax has been removed in Vue 2.

It should be either:

```
<v-chip small :class="`${project.status}`">
```

Or:

```
<v-chip small :class="project.status">
```

Notice that they are interchangeable only if `project.status` is a string.